# Copying files and dirs on remote server while excluding some of them

Tags: linux, ssh

Server 1 is connected to Server 2 via SSH.

We know this:
I can execute a command such as

"  ssh server2 "cp -rv /var/www /tmp"  "

which will copy the entire /var/www dir to /tmp.  However inside of /var/www we have the following structure(sample LS output below)

$ ls

/web1
/web2
/web3
file1.php
file2.php
file3.php

How can I execute a cp command that will exclude /web1, /web3, file1.php and file3.php  (obviously just copying web2 and file2 is not an option since there are significantly more files than just 6)

Note: I am using this to backup Server2 prior to RSYNCing from Server1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two poster's both have good suggestions about [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/ftp/rsync/rsync.html).  Here's a more complete outline of the process.

(1) You want to backup server 2 before you sync from server 1, so let's do that with `rsync`. Here's the command as seen from server 1 (assuming it has access to server 2):

```
ssh user@server2 "rsync $RSYNC_OPTS /var/www/ /path/to/backup"
```

(2) With server 2 backed up, let's now sync from server 1 (again, as seen from server 1)

```
rsync $RSYNC_OPTS /path/to/www/ user@server2:/var/www/
```

As long as you use sane `RSYNC_OPTS`, the backup and sync should both be reasonable. Richard had a reasonable suggestion for the options:

```
RSYNC_OPTS="--exclude-from rsync-exclude.txt --stats -avz --numeric-ids -e ssh"
```

If you want an accurate reproduction, I'd recommend `--delete` or `--delete-after` as well. Be sure to lookup details on any options you're unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 1):

For this you should really be using rsync.

I tend to uye an rsync-exclude.txt file to specify what I don't want as it's more future proof.

```
/public_ftp/.ftpquota
/tmp
/var/local/backups/rsyncs
/backup/rsync
/proc
/dev
```

so a command could be

```
rsync --exclude-from rsync-exclude.txt --stats -avz -e ssh \
      --numeric-ids /syncfrom/dir  user@example.com:/backup/sync-to-dir
```

edit::

In the case of a local server you can still use rsync, however you could also use tar and exclude what you don't want.

```
 (cd dir1;tar --exclude 'web2/*' -cf -) | (cd dir2; tar -xvf -)
```

or
     find dir1 dir2 >exclude-files (cd dir1;tar --exclude-from exclude-files -cf -) | (cd dir2; tar -xvf -)

Comment: rsync works when syncing one server to another.  However, just in case there are some inconsistencies, I want to backup the original server first, and THEN rsync.

Comment: maybe just write a awk/perl script to execute a list of cp would be the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing when deploying new releases to my webserver.  Is it possible for you to use rsync over ssh?  rsync allows you to specify an --exclude option and specify either the dirs/files on the command line or via a file. Here's a pretty good writeup that I've used in the past:
http://articles.slicehost.com/2007/10/10/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders

Comment: see my comment in response to Richard.

Answer (score 0):

Since what you want to do is "copy all files except those", following your example you could do this :

```
 ssh server2 "cp -rv /var/www/!(web1|web3|file1.php|file3.php) /tmp"
```

But remember that this is very ugly to backup your server :p

Comment: That's a good use for shell exclusions, but doesn't take into account deleted files and the like.